# arquillian add resources from main folder

Tags: jakarta-ee, war, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I have a problem inside the business code of our JAVA EE application server.
We access some files inside the `src/main/resources` folder with

```
  InputStream inputStream = Thread
                .currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(filePath);
```

In production this works, but I would like to test a part of code which use this functionality inside my arquillian test.

We are using shrinkwrap to generate our `test.war`.

```
 WebArchive testArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                .addPackages(true, "ch.microtronic.evending")
                .addAsWebInfResource("wildfly-ds.xml")
                .setWebXML(new File("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml"))
                .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml");
```

I have some trouble to add the resources from `src/main/resources` to the `test.war`.

I can only add files from `src/test/resources`.

Our directory structure looks like:

```
src
 |__main
 |   |__java
 |   |__resources
 |   |__webapp
 |   
 |__test
     |__java
     |__resources
```

What I have to do?

Comment: Have you tried something like `.addAsResource("src/main/resources", "/resources");`?

Comment: Yes. The problem is, that the start path inside `addAsResource()` is already inside `src/test/resources`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add files that are not in `src/test/resources` you just need to use an overloaded version `addAsResource(File, String)` instead of `addAsResource(String, String)`. For your example that would look like:

```
.addAsResource(new File("src/main/resources/test-persistence.xml"),"META-INF/persistence.xml");
```

I've just solved similar issue in my code, so this approach definitely works.

Answer (score 4):

This one-liner adds recursive all main resources from src:

```
testArchive.addAsResource(new File("src/main/resources/"), "");
```

this one for some resources postprocessed by maven:

```
testArchive.addAsResource(new File("target/classes/META-INF/"), "META-INF/");
```

Comment: The one liner is pretty handy. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To include a subtree I use the following.

Say that you need in your classpath all files under `src/main/resources/db/migration` as `db/migration/FILE_NAME`

```
Path resources_dir = Paths.get("src", "main", "resources");
Path migrations_dir = resources_dir.resolve(Paths.get("db", "migration"));
Files.walk(migrations_dir)
  .forEach((p) -> jar.addAsResource(p.toFile(),
                                    resources_dir.relativize(p).toString()));
```

relativize